# How can I control a rig with gamepad or vr controller

Tags: animation

I was watching a behind the scenes documentary on the first Jurassic Park movie. I noticed a controller called the "dinosaur input device" it was a physical rig that the animator's could use to move the characters on the computer. That sounds like a good idea for one animator to create animations quickly. Can something similar be accomplished in Blender with a gamepad or VR controller? And how?

Answer (score 0):

The topic you are intrested in is called *Motion Capture* and is quite vast.

**TLDR**: depending on your use case probably can't because you cant track enough axis.

The old school way of doing this is to build a **real world version of your rig**. Then you attach motion sensors often called Internal Mesurment Unit (IMU) that mesure each movement axis of each physical represented bone. This principal also exist in form of **motion capture suits** where you slip in.
When you have the motion data for each frame per sensor you convert it to FBX or blender keyframes usualy by python code. You also can build a plugin for blender that takes realtime input from the motion sensors so you can fiddel around with your rig and see wat happens in blender (there probably exist comercial products doing this)

Of course you dont have to track the data for every bone, but than you have to calculate it ither by smart IK rigging or by calculating the missing data yourself.

With a **Gamepad and VR controller** you dont have enough axis of fredom you can track.
A VR controler gives tracked in a room gives you one tracked translation and rotation. So you can use it to manipulate one object. Of course you have some butons so you could togle thro your bones and place them one by one .. but this seems quite tedious to do.
I think ther exist some gamepats with tracking as well. But still you need to track more than one thing for most rigs.

Ther is a solution to capture your motion to a rig using the Kinekt **depth sensor** for blender.

If you want to do lo entry cost motion capute probably **motion capture via computer vision** from webcam or video data is your way to go. There exist comercial products doing this.. and also code from research papers were you have to fiddle your way through.

Comment: `you dont have enough axis of fredom you can track` This is nonsense. You have exactly as many axes of freedom you'd need to control a bone. In many cases, I'm not animating  extensive rigs, nor may I be animating the entire rig at a single time. There are a plethora of cases where this sort of tracking would be **incredibly** useful, and yet (even in Jan '21) there isn't great support for this yet. It's a shame that this is the state of things.

Comment: jep .. one bone. If thats enough for your usecas ... fire up the sdk and write a small script to stream it into blender. Should be not to hard for a dev. gretings from BLN ;)